# search and compare data between dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an issue about merge of data-frame.
I have two data-frames as follow,

```
df1:
ID name-group status
1  bob,david  good
2  CC,robben  good
3  jack       bad

df2:
ID  leader   location
2   robben   JAPAN
3   jack     USA
4   bob      UK
```

I want to get a result as flow.

```
dft
ID  name-group Leader location
1   bob,david   
2   CC,robben  Robben JAPAN
3   jack       Jack   USA
```

the [Leader] and [location] will be merged when

```
[leader] in df2 **IN** [name-group] of df1
&
[ID] of df2 **＝** [ID] of df1
```

I have tried for loop, but its time-cost is very high.
any ideas for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't `bob` the leader of `bob,david`?

Comment: Hi unutbu, bob is the leader of bob,david, but the ID is different. ID of df2 must = ID of df1

Comment: Why dont u do a merge here, pd.merge(df1,df2,how = ‘left’ ,left_on = [‘ID’],right_on = [‘ID’])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the end of the post for runnable code. The proposed solution is in the function, `using_tidy`.

---

The main problem here is that having multiple names in `name-group`, separated
by commas, makes searching for membership difficult. If, instead, `df1` had each
member of `name-group` in its own row, then testing for membership would be
easy. That is, suppose `df1` looked like this:

```
   ID  name-group status
0   1  bob        good
0   1  david      good
1   2  CC         good
1   2  robben     good
2   3  jack       bad
```

Then you could simply merge `df1` and `df2` on `ID` and test if `leader`
*equals* `name-group`... almost (see why "almost" below).

Putting `df1` in tidy format ([PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf))
is the main idea in the solution below. The reason why it improves performance
is because testing for equality between two columns is much much faster than
testing if a column of strings are substrings of another column of strings, or
are members of a column containing a list of strings.

The reason why I said "almost" above is because there is another difficulty -- 
after merging `df1` and `df2` on `ID`, some rows are leaderless such as the `bob,david` row:

```
ID  name-group Leader location
1   bob,david
```

Since we simply want to keep these rows and we don't want to test if criteria #1 holds in this case, we need to treat these rows differently -- don't expand them.
We can handle this problem by separating the leaderless rows from those with potential leaders (see below).

---

The second criteria, that the IDs match is easy to enforce by merging `df1` and `df2` on `ID`:

```
dft = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')
```

The first criteria is that `dft['leader']` is in `dft['name-group']`.
This criteria could be expressed as

```
In [293]: dft.apply(lambda x: pd.isnull(x['leader']) or (x['leader'] in x['name-group'].split(',')), axis=1)
Out[293]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

but using `dft.apply(..., axis=1)` calls the lambda function once for each
row. This can be very slow if there are many rows in `dft`.

If there are many rows in `dft` we can do better by first converting `dft` to
tidy format ([PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf)) -- placing each
member in `dft['name-group']` on its own row. But first, let's split `dft` into 2
sub-DataFrames, those which have a leader, and those which don't:

```
has_leader = pd.notnull(dft['leader'])
leaderless, leaders = dft.loc[~has_leader, :], dft.loc[has_leader, :]
```

Now put the `leaders` in tidy format (one member per row):

```
member = leaders['name-group'].str.split(',', expand=True)
member = member.stack()
member.index = member.index.droplevel(1)
member.name = 'member'
leaders = pd.concat([member, leaders], axis=1)
```

The pay off for all this work is that criteria #1 can now be expressed by a fast calculation:

```
# this enforces criteria #1 (leader of df2 is in name-group of df1)
mask = (leaders['leader'] == leaders['member']) 
leaders = leaders.loc[mask, :]
leaders = leaders.drop('member', axis=1)
```

and the desired result is:

```
dft = pd.concat([leaderless, leaders], axis=0)
```

---

We had to do some work to get `df1` into tidy format. We need to benchmark to
determine if the cost of doing that extra work pays off by being able to compute criteria #1 faster.

Here is a benchmark using largish dataframes of 1000 rows for `df1` and `df2`:

```
In [356]: %timeit using_tidy(df1, df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop

In [357]: %timeit using_apply(df1, df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 98.2 ms per loop
```

The speed advantage of `using_tidy` over `using_apply` increases as the number
of rows in `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')` increases.

---

Here is the setup for the benchmark:

```
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name-group':['bob,david', 'CC,robben', 'jack'],
                    'status':['good','good','bad'],
                    'ID':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'leader':['robben','jack','bob'],
                    'location':['JAPAN','USA','UK'],
                    'ID':[2,3,4]})

def using_apply(df1, df2):
    dft = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')
    mask = dft.apply(lambda x: pd.isnull(x['leader']) or (x['leader'] in x['name-group'].split(',')), axis=1)
    return dft.loc[mask, :]

def using_tidy(df1, df2):
    # this enforces criteria #2 (the IDs are the same)
    dft = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')

    # split dft into 2 sub-DataFrames, based on rows which have a leader and those which do not.
    has_leader = pd.notnull(dft['leader'])
    leaderless, leaders = dft.loc[~has_leader, :], dft.loc[has_leader, :]

    # expand leaders so each member in name-group has its own row
    member = leaders['name-group'].str.split(',', expand=True)
    member = member.stack()
    member.index = member.index.droplevel(1)
    member.name = 'member'
    leaders = pd.concat([member, leaders], axis=1)

    # this enforces criteria #1 (leader of df2 is in name-group of df1)
    mask = (leaders['leader'] == leaders['member']) 
    leaders = leaders.loc[mask, :]
    leaders = leaders.drop('member', axis=1)

    dft = pd.concat([leaderless, leaders], axis=0)
    return dft

def make_random_str_array(letters=string.ascii_uppercase, strlen=10, size=100):
    return (np.random.choice(list(letters), size*strlen)
            .view('|U{}'.format(strlen)))

def make_dfs(N=1000):
    names = make_random_str_array(strlen=4, size=10)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'name-group':[','.join(np.random.choice(names, size=np.random.randint(1,10), replace=False)) for i in range(N)],
        'status':np.random.choice(['good','bad'], size=N),
        'ID':np.random.randint(4, size=N)})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'leader':np.random.choice(names, size=N),
        'location':np.random.randint(10, size=N),
        'ID':np.random.randint(4, size=N)})

    return df1, df2

df1, df2 = make_dfs()
```

Comment: Thank you, @unubu, please let me try your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you use

```
Dft = pd.merge(df1,df2,how=‘left’,left_on = [‘ID’],right_on =[‘ID’])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is not a good way to address this condition: [leader] in df2 **IN** [name-group] of df1